# C++ - string Input in a specific way

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, character

I want to take input from user in a specific way like in the following manner :

```
L1 L2 L3 N
```

L1,L2,L3 are strings separated by whitespace. And N is a integer. I tried using `cin` but it was slow. I need to get the input fast. Also the string L2 in repeated N times. So I have to store  `l1 + l2*N + l3`. I tried string but it's becoming too slow. I'm getting TLE.

Here's how I stored them :

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
 string l1,l2,l3;
  int n;
  cin>>l1>>l2>>l3>>n;
  string r;
 r.reserve(l1.size()+n * l2.size()+l3.size());
r += l1;
 for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
  r +=l2;

 r += l3;
 cout<<r<<endl;
return 0;
 }

And then iterated it in 2 separate for loops with maximum 1000 iterations in each loop.
```

How can I efficiently store them ? I know about vectors but I'm not good at them. So if anyone knows how to store them in this sequence in vector please help me out. Or if they could be stored on character array, then how to do that  way ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the input that is slowing you down and not you algorithm?

Comment: I doubt that it's `cin` being too slow, it's most likely the current method you have for reading in the strings. 

Is/are the string(s) L2*N space separated, or is/are it/they concatenated together (so technically just one long string)?

The answer to how you should store them is entirely dependent on what you want to use the strings for afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, I think so because all I did in my rest of the code was to iterate the string I.e. `(l1+l2*n+l3)` in 2 separate `for loop` which would run for the worst case 1000 times.

Comment: How about if you show us a concrete example of the input format, and the relevant parts of your current code for reading it?

Comment: @SeanPianka the string is one long concatenated string consisting of `l1 then l2 concatenated n times and then l3 without any spaces` and all I need to do is to iterate through them to count frequency of 1 specific character after another specific character from end of the string.

Comment: Can you please post real code?  This will not compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver It should compile now.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I have included the code.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<n;i++)  r +=l2;` is going to do a lot of work.  especially if you are doing this in some nested for loops up to 1,000,000 times.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see. Thanks. But how do I concatenate the `string l2 n times` in a  faster way ?

Comment: @samthornton [Zero output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43957d1fa624cdce)

Comment: I'm compiling it with C++14. Please try it with that compiler. It is compiling on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So let's start by isolating the actual reading from the other code:

```
struct foo { 
    std::string l1, l2, l3; 
    int n;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, foo &f) { 
       return is >> f.l1, >> f.l2 >> f.l3 >> n;
    }
};
```

With that we can read in a file full of these records into a vector with something like this:

```
std::vector<foo> data { std::istream_iterator<foo>(infile), {} };
```

I'd guess that (by itself) won't be a bottleneck. There are probably faster ways to do the job if truly necessary, but I doubt it's really needed.

Based on the comments on how the searching needs to be done, we can do the searching without ever expanding the second string out to `n` occurrences of `l2`.

The searching is for one character from the beginning of the string up until the last (right-most) occurrence of some other character.

Since that "end" pattern is a single character, we can do this pretty easily without expanding the middle string (`L2`) at all. The logic is basically:

```
if L3 contains end_pattern
   total = count(L1) + count(L2) * n + count(L3.substr(0, pattern_pos))
else if L2 contains end_pattern
    total = count(L1) + count(L2) * (n-1) + count(L2.substr(0, pattern_pos))
else if L1 contains end_pattern
    total = count(L1.substr(0, pattern_pos))
else
    total = 0; // pattern isn't present anywhere
```

At least as described in the comments, there doesn't seem to be any need for the O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm described in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And for the searching part , suppose if I have this input `aabba bbba aaaa 2` now I want to calculate no of a's after the first b from right side. Can it be done without using concatenation of l2 n times ?

Comment: @samthornton: What does "after the first B from right side" mean?

Comment: I mean I want to calculate no of a's from right side but only after encountering at least 1 b or else the count will be zero. For eg `ba ab aa 4` is the input then it becomes `ba abababab aa` (ignore whitespace) now I want to calculate number of a's from right side I.e. `index = string.size() -1` but only after I encounter one b. That is I will.iterare from right side and after seeing one b I will count the nunber of a's. Here number of a's after first b from right side are `5`.

Comment: I also developed the same scheme. I realised how stupid it was to ask it. Thanks for your time and effort.